# How to specify source files to Jasmine for node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I'm developing a node.js library. I want to use gulp-jasmine to launch my tests.

I can't find anywhere in Jasmine's doc[1] nor in gulp-jasmine's doc[2] how to specify where are located my source files. Every projects using jasmine I can find on Github do only specify the spec files in their jasmine.json.

Is there some sort of pattern I should be using with the file system?

**Links**

1. https://jasmine.github.io/2.4/node.html
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jasmine/

Answer (score 0):

You should simply `require` corresponding source file(s) in spec file, e.g.

```
var module = require("../module");

describe("add2and3", function () {
  it("should add 2 and 3", function () {
    expect(module.add2and3()).toBe(5);
  });
});
```